# NoReverseMatch error when using Django url template tag with optional parameters, but NOT when visiting the URL in the browser

Tags: python, django, url, django-templates

I have a URL that needs to account for the following patterns:

- localhost:8000/staffing-agencies
- localhost:8000/staffing-agencies/90210 (zip code)
- localhost:8000/staffing-agencies/portland-or (city-state)

When I type in any of these urls in my browser, they all work as expected. However, I'm getting a `NoReverseMatch` error when I try to refer to this URL from Django's url template tag.

Here are my relevant url.py files:

```
# From urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('bos.apps.search.urls', namespace='search',
                       app_name='search')),
)

# From search/urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('bos.apps.search',
    url(r'^staffing-agencies/'
        r'((?P<city>[a-zA-Z]+)-(?P<state>[a-zA-Z]{2}))?'
        r'((?P<zip>[0-9]{5}))?$',
        'views.main', name='main'),
)
```

I thought it might be something to do with the optional parameters, but all of these variances throw the `NoReverseMatch` error:

```
<a href="{% url "search:main" zip=97214 %}">Test</a>
<a href="{% url "search:main" city="portland" state="or" %}">Test</a>
```

This variance does NOT throw an error:

```
<a href="{% url "search:main" %}">Test</a>
```

I'm using Django 1.6.5

Answer (score 1):

This not better solution, this is one of solution

```
url(r'^staffing-agencies/(?P<city>[a-zA-Z]+)*-(?P<state>[a-zA-Z]{2})*?(?P<zip>[0-9]{5})*?$',
        'views.main', name='main'),
```

in views:

```
def main(request, city=None, state=None, zip=None):
```

in html:

```
<a href="{% url "search:main"  city='sadasd' state='ds' zip=12345 %}">Test</a>
```

In this case url work like this,

- localhost:8000/staffing-agencies
- localhost:8000/staffing-agencies/-90210 (zip code)
- localhost:8000/staffing-agencies/portland-or (city-state)